# How to change class dynamically in svelte?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to change 2023-10-25 div's background. However, It doesn't work. What should I do?

```
<script>
let mydate = [new Date(2023, 9, 24).toDateString()];

const getClass = (date) => {
  return mydate.includes(date) ? "myclass": ""
}
</script>
<style>
.myclass { background-color: yellow; } </style>
<button on:click={() => {
  mydate = [...mydate, new Date(2023, 9, 25)]
}}>click</button>
<div class={getClass(new Date(2023, 9, 24).toDateString())}>{new Date(2023, 9, 24)}</div>
<div class={getClass(new Date(2023, 9, 25).toDateString())}>{new Date(2023, 9, 25)}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency from `getClass` to `mydate` is "hidden".

You can declare it reactively to make it track variables in its body.

There also appears to be an error since you add the new date on click without converting it to a string. This would need to be changed first for `includes` to work.

```js
$: getClass = date => mydate.includes(date) ? "myclass" : "";
```

(Otherwise it would only get called again when the argument, in this case `date`, changes.)

Comment: To make things cleaner can't you put in your html : `<div class:myclass={getClass(new Date(2023, 9, 24).toDateString())}}></div>` while keeping @H.B. answer